# Defined variable showing as undefined in error console

Tags: javascript, variables

I have a function that searches a database table via ajax.
This is the function

```
function find_file(query)
    {
        var xtoken = $("input[name='xtoken']").val();
        var uri = site_url+'admin/media/search';
        //make request to controller method
        $.get(uri,{ 'xtoken' : xtoken,'query':query },
        function(data) {
            var dataLength = data.length;
            if(dataLength < 1)
            {
                $.gritter.add({title:'Notice',text:'No matching results',sticky:false,time:'3000'});
            }else {
                var dataGrid = $('#files table tbody');
                dataGrid.html('');
                $.each(data,function(index,file)
                {
                    var media_thumbnail ="";
                    if((file.file_type == "image/jpeg") || (file.file_type == "image/png") || (file.file_type == "image/png"))
                    {
                        media_thumbnail = '<img src="'+file.file_path+'" height="60" width="46" />';
                    }
                    if((file.file_type == "audio/mp3") || (file.file_type == "audio/wma"))
                    {
                        media_thumbnail = '<img src="'+site_url+'assets/admin/audio.png" />';
                    }
                    dataGrid.append(
                        '<tr class="files" id="'+file.file_id+'">'+
                            '<td><input id="file_id" type="checkbox" name="file_id[]" value="'+file.file_id+'" /></td>'+
                            '<td>'+
                                '<div class="media_preview">'+media_thumbail+'</div>'+
                                '<a href="'+site_url+'admin/media/editmedia/'+file.file_id+'">'+file.file_name+'</a>'+
                            '</td>'+
                             '<td>'+file.file_type+'</td>'+
                             '<td>'+file.author+'</td>'+
                             '<td>'+file.upload_date+'</td>'+
                        '</tr>'
                    );
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

When the code executes, I get an error saying var media_thumbnail is undefined, even after I declare the variable as empty " `var media_thumbnail = "";` "
Am setting  the value of the var media_thumbail after testing an object from the JSON return of the ajax call.
See this part of the code

```
var media_thumbnail ="";
                    if((file.file_type == "image/jpeg") || (file.file_type == "image/png") || (file.file_type == "image/png"))
                    {
                        media_thumbnail = '<img src="'+file.file_path+'" height="60" width="46" />';
                    }
                    if((file.file_type == "audio/mp3") || (file.file_type == "audio/wma"))
                    {
                        media_thumbnail = '<img src="'+site_url+'assets/admin/audio.png" />';
                    }
```

What is wrong with my function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misspelled the variable reference:

```
'<div class="media_preview">'+media_thumbail+'</div>'+
                                         ^ missing 'n'
```

Answer (score 2):

`media_thumbail` is not the same as `media_thumbnail`. You have a typo there:

```
'<div class="media_preview">'+media_thumbail+'</div>'+
```

should be

```
'<div class="media_preview">'+media_thumbnail+'</div>'+
```

See the missing `n` there?

Comment: Someone should really flag this question for deletion, it in no way brings any new knowledge to SO.

Comment: Is that the point of the site? I thought it was a programmer community that answers problems. If it was just a dumb opinion then yeah, delete, but this guy is having a problem and it looks like he may have an answer thanks to this place. Gratitude may convince him to help out in the future.

Comment: @KaiQing I wasn't trying to insult his/her intelligence. I'm glad he/she found an answer here. I just don't see how the universe would at all be affected by deleting this.

Comment: @puk - Deleting his question would be like telling him/her: Your question was so stupid, it has no place in the universe. We all make typo's, and I've sure spent ENORMOUS amounts of time on tracking down typos. This is a valid use case of SO, even if this particular question won't be of any help for generations to come.

Comment: @JosephSilber I spent 2 hours debugging my php code today all b/c I had `fileName` instead of `filename`. But if I posted that here I'd feel super lousy if someone pointed it out, to the point that I'd request it be deleted myself.

Comment: and if someone in the future google searches defined variable undefined they may happen across this and see that it could be a simple typo in an enormous, convoluted function and review their own work before coming here for specific help. Dont pretend little things like this dont get you every now and then. I almost lost a hundred thousand dollar client cause I defined a variable in a script tag with a facebook api call that broke - baffled. SO helped. Maybe someone else will avoid the same oversight.

Comment: There's a [campaign to clean up Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167342/187073) by removing these typo-related questions - we could really use your help! Would you mind pitching in a little by casting a close vote on this question?